# Where can I learn how to deploy ASP.NET 4 MVC 2 applications to IIS7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I've done a significant amount of searching and am having difficulty finding people who have encountered a similar problem.

I have gone into the properties for my project and set it to use the local IIS web server instead of the VS Dev server. It created the virtual directory just fine. When I attempt to browse to the site, I receive the following error:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I haven't done any custom routing rules for my project, so all of that is in its default state. The only other thing that I can think of is that there is something special that needs to be done to set up the "default" page for an MVC 2 deployment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30128\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

That solved it for me in the past.  (remove the "64" if you're on 32-bit)

Comment: This advice allowed me to reach the Home index, but if I attempt to navigate to any other view I get a "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." Any clue on that one? Thank you for your help so far, by the way.

Comment: No, not sure.  I'm happy to help here, but you may have better luck starting a new question and getting a new slew of programmers to respond. :)   Otherwise, I'd need to know more about what the controller is named, what your routing rules look like, etc.